# ¿Cómo traducir de fortran "Read( 1 , * )x,y,z" a python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

En otras palabras, de un archivo que contiene datos separados por una coma u otro separador, ¿cómo puedo leer y asignar a variables con Python?

En concreto tengo un archivo llamado `datos.dat` que contiene estas lineas:

```
entrada.dat
salida.dat
0.5,10,5
150,800,0.002
```

De fortran tengo:

```
Open(1, file='datos.dat')
Read(1,'(A)')ent
Read(1,'(A)')sal
Read(1,*)var1,var2,var3
Read(1,*)NE,NR,ETA

demas_cosas()
```

Pero necesito traducir el script a Python 2 y se me ocurre algo así:

```
from sys import argv

script, datos = argv

arx = open(datos, "r")
ent = arx.readline(1)
sal = arx.readline(2)
var[]= arx.readline(3).split(,) # no sé si sea valida esta sintaxis???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola cavereaper y bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Voy a suponer dos cosas:

1. Quieres que las variables (`var1`, `var2`,
   `var3`, `NE`, `NR`,
   `ETA`) sean de tipo `float` para poder operar
   con ellas.
2. Las variables `ent` y `sal` no contengan el salto de linea (`\n`) al final.

El código en Python podría ser:

```
with open('datos.dat', "r") as arx:
    ent = arx.readline().rstrip('\n')
    sal = arx.readline().rstrip('\n')
    var1, var2, var3 = map(float, arx.readline().split(','))
    NE, NR, ETA = map(float, arx.readline().split(','))

#Podemos ver los resultados de la lectura imprimiendo las variables:
print ent
print sal
print var1, var2, var3
print NE, NR, ETA
```